# New Button for each line of a text file?

Tags: c#, for-loop, dynamic, controls

I am trying to dynamically create a new button for each line of a text file.

My problem is that no matter how many lines the text file has, it only ever generates a single button.

The code:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader
  (@"D:\SupportDash\Settings\Settings.txt");

string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\SupportDash\Settings\Settings.txt");
        foreach(String row in lines)
        {        

            Button Buttona = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            Buttona.Text = "Test";
            Buttona.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            Buttona.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(85,28);
            Buttona.Click += (s, e) => 
            {
                Form DynamicForm = new Form();
                DynamicForm.Show();

            };

            groupBox2.Controls.Add(Button);

            counter++;

        }

        file.Close();
    }
```

I've also tried using a while and a do-while loop. -The same thing happens.

My text file is separated by a carriage return. (Its generated in-program using File.ApendAllText();)

Is it a problem being caused by my program only thinking there is one huge line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting all buttons at the same `Location`, so it may appear there is only one button, when in fact there is one button per line, they are just all on top of each other.

Try incrementing the Location's `Top` every time through the loop or use a panel control that supports wrapping.

Comment: Brilliant, I don't know why I assumed it would do that for me. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to position each new button at a new position for example

where your setting

```
Buttona.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(85,28);
```

call something like

```
var buttonHeight = 10;

Buttona.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(85,28 + (count * buttonHeight  ));
```

you are actually creating multiple buttons but they are all on top of each other.